# What does "bei drei auf den Bäumen" mean in this sentence?

Tags: idiom

> Wer sich in eine Idee verliebt, der verliebt sich womöglich in alles, was nicht **bei drei auf den Bäumen** ist.

This phrase doesn't make sense to me so I'm wondering if it's an idiom or something that is not mean to be taken literally.

Comment: 1, 2, 3 ... :-D

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Viel Vergnügen. Oder bist du schon oben? ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### nicht bei drei

When you ask children to do something as soon as possible (for example: going to bed), then you often say something like this:

> Ich zähle bis drei. Wenn Du **bei drei nicht** im Bett bist, fahren wir morgen nicht in den Zoo. Eins - zwei - drei.
>   I count up to three. If you are **not** in bed **at three**, tomorrow we will not go to the zoo. One - two - three.

So, *»Etwas nicht bis drei tun«* means to do it too late.

---

### auf den Bäumen

If you try to escape from a predator or someone who is after you, it can be a good idea to climb on a tree as fast as possible. When more persons are fleeing, then you need many trees to climb on.

---

Together you get this:

> wer nicht bei drei auf den Bäumen ist
>   who doesn't escape fast enough

So, this is your sentence:

> Wer sich in eine Idee verliebt, der verliebt sich womöglich in alles, **was nicht bei drei auf den Bäumen ist.**
>   Who falls in love with an idea, may fall in love with everything **that doesn't escape fast enough.**

Comment: This is a good first half of an answer -- it is misleading, however, insofar that it completely ignores that any German over let's say 14 will understand the sexual connotation.

Comment: But where is the sexual connotation in »in eine Idee verliebt sein«? I don't know the context of the sentence in the question, but although »bei 3 auf den Bäumen sein« has a sexual connotation, I think it is irrelevant here.

Comment: Here is the context, under "Reality Check" - https://ze.tt/wie-es-ist-wenn-wir-uns-nicht-in-die-person-sondern-in-eine-idee-verlieben/?utm_content=zeitde_redpost_zmo_link_sf&utm_campaign=ref&utm_source=facebook_zonaudev_int&utm_term=facebook_zonaudev_int&utm_medium=sm&wt_zmc=sm.int.zonaudev.facebook.ref.zeitde.redpost_zmo.link.sf

Comment: Hubert, Du hast natürlich Recht, dass im zitierten Satz keine *oberflächliche* sexuelle Konnotation vorliegt. Wer die Redewendung "bei drei auf den Bäumen" im deutschsprachigen Raum hört, wird m.E. aber immer *auch* im Hinterkopf haben. Das sollte ein Nichtmuttersprachler wissen, damit er die Phrase nicht in aller Unschuld in einem unpassenden Kontext verwendet.

Comment: @Mac Ich bin Muttersprachler und kenne die Phrase schon ewig. Eine sexuelle Assoziation habe ich nur bei entsprechendem Kontext, wie in tofros Beispiel. Ansonsten absolut nicht. Nach dem Lesen der Antworten und Kommentare hier frage ich mich, ob es einen Bedeutungswandel gibt/gab oder einen unterschiedlichen in verschiedenen Altersgruppen/Regionen o.a.

Comment: @Marzipanherz: Hmm, das kann natürlich sein, dass es hier demographische/geographische Unterschiede gibt ... Sollte aber ein Wandel stattgefunden haben, gehe ich davon aus, dass der ursprünglich sexuelle Unterton sich langsam verliert. (Full disclosure: Ich gehöre wohl eher zur älteren Nutzergruppe :))

Comment: @Mac und ich hätte gedacht, der sexuelle Unterton ist _neu_, weil _ich_ mich zu den älteren Nutzen zähle :D

Comment: **Für die älteren unter uns:** der Spruch stammt wahrscheinlich von 1998 (Die Ärzte) und hatte von daher ganze 20 Jahre Zeit, sich zu entschärfen. Man muss diese Herkunft als Nicht-Muttersprachler schon wissen, denn sonst läuft man eventuell in ein offenes Messer.

Comment: Ergänzend zu Takkats Forschungen: Zumindest in Bayern gab's den Spruch *lange* vor '98 (auf jeden Fall in den 80ern)

Comment: @Mac: spannend! Es taucht vor 1998 nirgends in den Suchmaschinen auf, auch nicht in Google books.

Comment: @Takkat: »bei drei auf den Bäumen« finde ich in diesem Spiegel-Artikel vom 15.7.1996: http://www.spiegel.de/spiegel/print/d-8947523.html und in diesem Artikel von 17.03.1997: http://www.spiegel.de/spiegel/print/d-8680610.html Offenbar war dieser Spruch schon 1996 in der deutschen Musikerszene gebräuchlich, und die Ärzte haben diese Floskel dann in ihren Song »Männer sind Schweine« gepackt und im zweiten Quartal 1998 veröffentlicht.

Answer (score 4):

It is an idiom originating from a vulgar sexual context:

> Sie wollen alles begatten, was nicht bei drei auf den Bäumen ist <sup>[Die Ärzte: Männer sind Schweine](https://genius.com/Die-arzte-manner-sind-schweine-lyrics)</sup>
>   *They want to get laid anybody who is not on the tree by count on three.*

With this idiom two generally known actions are connected. One is the kids play *count on three*, the other is from hunting, when the prey tries to escape by climbing a tree.

When using this idiom we need to keep in mind that by the association of gameplay, hunting, and sexual partners being treated as prey the evolving idiom may still be received as sexist (if not misogynist) even after it was put into another context.

---

**Note on the origin:** The quote above is of a famous German song from 1998. It was used before but it may be this song what made it so popular.

Comment: @Renasaurus: This is the answer you're looking for. The English equivalent is "he'll *** anything with a pulse"

Comment: This explanation is good and brief. Still, in my experience, *alles was nicht bei drei auf den Bäumen ist* is not necessarily related to rude sexualism. I so far have heard it **exclusively in work context** in larger organisations when some hierarch tried to assign tasks that nobody likes to people who out of a sudden will all look very busy with some paperwork, in order to not get into eye contact with the hierarch. The application of the expression on sexual behaviour is, for my understanding, only one of many.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: I fully agree. Statements like "Die kaufen alle potenziellen Mitbewerber auf, die nicht bei drei auf den Bäumen sind." oder "Und dann wird jeder, der nicht bei drei auf den Bäumen ist, mit Klagen überzogen." are commonplace and have no sexual undertone, either.

Comment: I knew the phrase long before "Die Ärzte" used it in their song. It originally doesn't have a sexual connotation either, but simply means "somebody, who is too slow".

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: that's interesting too... do you have any quote or reference? Google, incl. Google books appear to not find it before 1998 and later it mostly is in said sexist usage. Maybe the wording was different? Was that a regional thing? I never heard it before *Die Ärzte*.

Comment: Memory may not serve me well, but such a recent origin seems implausible to me also."Originating"? Looks to me as if Die Aerzte made their mark in shifting that into that direction: [Bohlen used it differently, in 96](http://www.spiegel.de/spiegel/print/d-8947523.html)

Comment: [Das lag zu einem großen Teil auch an der kompromisslosen Brutalität des Sounds, der so urwüchsig aus den Boxen trümmerte und jedem die Fresse polierte, der nicht bei drei auf dem Baum ist.](https://www.laut.de/Slayer/Alben/Reign-In-Blood-18123)

Comment: Das Metal-Hammer Archive zeigt ebenfalls [einige Treffer für die Phrase an](https://www.metal-hammer.de/page/4/?s=bei+drei+auf+den+bäumen) aber das ist ne Paywall. Wer da vielleicht ein persönliches Archiv oder Zugang hat…? Oder [Geduld](https://www.musikexpress.de/wp-content/uploads/zeitung/metalhammer/wfgtKtQChx4w6/index.html#/html5///page/18)

Answer (score 2):

This moderately established phrase combines two components:

- a (short) time span, defined by somebody loudly counting (in this case to three). My first association is a childrens game, where one child covers its eyes, count *eins-zwei-drei-um* and on the last syllable uncovers its eyes and turns the head. The other children have in the meanwhile attempted approach from the back of the first child to touch it, but must take care, to stop motion before *um*, since in case of detection they have to start gain. As other answers show, different associations exist.
- the quite generic assumption, that one gets out of danger (e.g. being hunted by wolves, tigers, etc.) by climbing a tree, since one gets out of sight, and the beast may not be able to follow by also climbing. The plural *Bäume* indicates, that more than one person is affected, each one climbing a separate tree.

So anybody, who matches *bei drei nicht auf den Bäumen sein*, failed to get get out of danger fast enough.

Comment: Der Ankündigungseffekt von "bei drei" ist ein wenig unterbelichtet und "each one […] a seperate tree" klingt wie "nicht nötige Spezifizierung": auf einem Ast haben oft mehrere Platz, mehrere Äste = even more real-estate…

Answer (score -3):

wer es nicht schafft bei 3 auf den Bäumen zu sein, muss ein notorischer Verlierer sein. Das will diese Redewendung sagen.

> Bei drei

Im Gegensatz zur NASA, deren Countdowns auf 0 gehen, stellt man Ultimaten im deutschsprachigen Raum meist, in dem man bis 3 zählt.

```
Wenn Du bei drei nicht im Bett bist ...

Wenn ich bis drei das Smartphone nicht zurück habe ...
```

> auf den Bäumen

Man soll sich also eine Situation vorstellen, in der bei einer unausgesprochenen Strafe alle in ca. 3 Sekunden auf die Bäume sollen. In Deutschland gibt es zwar viele Bäume, aber in Sekunden **an** einem Baum zu sein ist meist schon nicht möglich, geschweige denn **auf** einem Baum. Weder sind wir alle passionierte Baumkletterer, noch sind die Bäume danach. Viele sind zu klein und schwach um drauf zu klettern, vor allem die Äste der Nadelbäume. Die stärkeren haben oft keine Äste in Bodennähe.

Man muss sich schon eine Horde Affen vorstellen, denen es keine Schwierigkeiten macht auch ungünstige, astarme Bäume zu erklimmen und die Grundfertigkeit einen Baum zu erklimmen hat jeder Affe. Ein Affe, der es nicht schafft bei 3 auf den Bäumen zu sein muss also ein übermäßig ungeschickter, womöglich sehr dummer oder stark übermüdeter Affe sein.

Comment: Ich interpretiere "bei 3 auf den Bäumen" nicht so, dass jemand, der das nicht schafft, ein geborener Verlierer ist, sondern lediglich, dass er in einer Situation eben nicht schnell genug reagiert.

Comment: Someone's barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: Da es keinen wirklichen Aufruf oder Anlass gibt, die Bäume zu erklimmen, muss der Personenkreis wohl darüber bestimmt sein regelmäßig oder wahrscheinlich nicht bei 3 auf den Bäumen zu sein. Leute, die zufällig nicht bei 3 auf den Bäumen sind, weil sie vielleicht weiter von einem solchen weg stehen, macht zu klassifizieren keinen Sinn, weil es sie ja gerade nicht klassifiziert, wenn sie nur zufällig nicht rechtzeitig auf dem Baum sind. Da vielleicht manche das "geborene Verlierer" wörtlich nehmen schwäche ich die Formulierung mal ab.

Answer (score -3):

> … der verliebt sich in alles, was nicht bei drei auf den Bäumen ist.

This is a well-known pun on the verb *besteigen*, which means *to climb* a mountain or a tree, but also *to mount* a horse or … the opposite sex.

Comment: Es ist bezeichnend, dass gerade diejenige Antwort abgewertet wird, die erwähnt, wo das überhaupt herkommt. Schade.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: Das Problem ist weniger, dass es hier um Sex geht, sondern dass es eben *kein* Wortspiel auf "besteigen" ist, sondern darum, dass das Subjekt alles nimmt, was sich nicht schnell genug in Sicherheit bringen kann. (Er besteigt ja eben gerade die, die *nicht* auf den Bäumen sind, oder?)

Comment: Die ursprüngliche Version ist *Der besteigt alles, was nicht bei drei auf'm Baum ist.* Nur den Baum, den besteigt er also nicht. Damit ist auch klar, was mit *besteigen* im ersten Satzteil gemeint ist.

Comment: @Janka: Das mag ja sein, aber gerade der Teil mit *besteigen* kam ja in dem Textfragment des OP überhaupt nicht vor. Der Teil, der vorkam, nämlich das zügige (auf den Bäumen) Schutz Suchen, hat mit den verschiedenen Bedeutungen von *besteigen*, die du aufzählst, an sich nichts zu tun, und wird in dieser Antwort auch überhaupt nicht erklärt.

Comment: Wieso the **opposite** sex?